# What is the C++ global regex expression?

Tags: c++, regex

In C++, I am trying to match this string. "CREATE=NO\nBOB=HI" to grab the content after the = sign and it will not grab the char . When I run my program, it will only grab the first match which is NO.

> matches[0] = CREATE=NO
>
> > matches[1] = NO

But for grabbing BOB=HI, it does not even match it. Here is my code.

```
int main() {
std::string parse = "CREATE=NO\nBOB=HI";
std::cout << parse << std::endl;
std::string regexp = "\\w+=(\\w+)";
std::smatch matches;
std::regex regex(regexp);
std::regex_search(parse, matches, regex);
std::cout << "The size is " << matches.size() << std::endl;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << "Matches " << i << ": " << matches[i] << std::endl;
}
std::cin.get();
```

}

> What I'm trying to do is get NO and HI but it only grabs NO

Comment: There is a saying along the lines of "I have a problem. I solved it using regexes. Now I have *two* problems!" While regular expressions are powerful and can be used to beautifully solve some problems, it's not a silver bullet and can't be used to solve all problems. It's also very complex to use which easily leads to more problems than before. Unless you are *forced* to use regular expressions, I suggest you try to come up with a simpler solution not using them.

Comment: One way to simplify things is to split the input on the newline first, into a vector of strings in the format `"key=value"`. This can easily be done using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Once that is done it's very easy to split that into separate `"key"` and `"value"` strings (again you could use `std::istringstream` and `std::getline`, or even a simple regular expression).